# Drop_duplicates fails to drop exact match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am scanning for duplicate rows in imported data and I am using pd.duplicated & pd.drop_duplicates to find & drop duplicate rows. I have a set of rows which seem to be exact duplicates. Previously the columns were in a different order, but I merged the data & the problem persists.

**EDIT:** I should have noted that my data is mixed float/str, so I cannot use numpy methods. I want the solution to be adaptable to variable numbers of columns, so I cannot manually reorder them.

Example of two rows that are not being flagged by drop_duplicates:

```
Datetime               2019-09-05 17:36:38
Site Name                      glacier hut
Chlorophyll RFU                       0.81
Chlorophyll ug/L                      2.93
Cond µS/cm                          2593.8
fDOM QSU                             76.75
fDOM RFU                             24.79
nLF Cond µS/cm                      3061.3
ODO % sat                             78.6
ODO % local                           78.6
ODO mg/L                              7.44
ORP mV                               196.9
Sal psu                               1.58
SpCond µS/cm                          3024
BGA PC RFU                            -0.1
BGA PC ug/L                           -0.1
TDS mg/L                              1966
Turbidity FNU                        19.49
TSS mg/L                                 0
Wiper Position volt                  1.211
pH                                    4.41
pH mV                                149.2
Temp °C                             17.553
Battery V                              5.9
Cable Pwr V                              0
sonde_id                         19E100810
field_monitor                            0
```

```
Datetime               2019-09-05 17:36:38
Site Name                      glacier hut
Chlorophyll RFU                       0.81
Chlorophyll ug/L                      2.93
Cond µS/cm                          2593.8
fDOM QSU                             76.75
fDOM RFU                             24.79
nLF Cond µS/cm                      3061.3
ODO % sat                             78.6
ODO % local                           78.6
ODO mg/L                              7.44
ORP mV                               196.9
Sal psu                               1.58
SpCond µS/cm                          3024
BGA PC RFU                            -0.1
BGA PC ug/L                           -0.1
TDS mg/L                              1966
Turbidity FNU                        19.49
TSS mg/L                                 0
Wiper Position volt                  1.211
pH                                    4.41
pH mV                                149.2
Temp °C                             17.553
Battery V                              5.9
Cable Pwr V                              0
sonde_id                         19E100810
field_monitor                            0
```

Both also have identical dtypes.

```
Datetime               datetime64[ns]
Site Name                      object
Chlorophyll RFU               float64
Chlorophyll ug/L              float64
Cond µS/cm                    float64
fDOM QSU                      float64
fDOM RFU                      float64
nLF Cond µS/cm                float64
ODO % sat                     float64
ODO % local                   float64
ODO mg/L                      float64
ORP mV                        float64
Sal psu                       float64
SpCond µS/cm                  float64
BGA PC RFU                    float64
BGA PC ug/L                   float64
TDS mg/L                      float64
Turbidity FNU                 float64
TSS mg/L                      float64
Wiper Position volt           float64
pH                            float64
pH mV                         float64
Temp °C                       float64
Battery V                     float64
Cable Pwr V                   float64
sonde_id                       object
field_monitor                 float64
```

```
Datetime               datetime64[ns]
Site Name                      object
Chlorophyll RFU               float64
Chlorophyll ug/L              float64
Cond µS/cm                    float64
fDOM QSU                      float64
fDOM RFU                      float64
nLF Cond µS/cm                float64
ODO % sat                     float64
ODO % local                   float64
ODO mg/L                      float64
ORP mV                        float64
Sal psu                       float64
SpCond µS/cm                  float64
BGA PC RFU                    float64
BGA PC ug/L                   float64
TDS mg/L                      float64
Turbidity FNU                 float64
TSS mg/L                      float64
Wiper Position volt           float64
pH                            float64
pH mV                         float64
Temp °C                       float64
Battery V                     float64
Cable Pwr V                   float64
sonde_id                       object
field_monitor                 float64
```

Comment: Yes, they do care about column orders. A case for 2 columns is [here](https://stackoveflow.com/questions/58592606/find-symmetric-pairs-quickly-in-numpy/58592764#58592764) which can also be generalized for several columns.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang. I'm surprised this isn't an option in either function. Hell, I'm still surprised pd.unique can't handle multiple dimensions. This must be a common problem!

Comment: @QuangHoang Unfortunately I don't think that solution will work for my case. The data is mixed floats & strings and there are too many columns (& number is dynamic depending on input) to manually reorder. Updated question with these details.

Comment: Only pay attention to the columns of interest, separate float and string columns and work on them separately.

Comment: @QuangHoang Data was merged so everything is in the same order but drop_duplicates still doesn't pick it up for some reason.

Comment: I created a dataframe with two rows, and the data given above, and drop_duplicates works well (and so is duplicated). Could you please provide the data in a format that would allow us to recreate it exactly as you have it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for doing that @Roy2012. I just went through each column to check equivalence and the culprit is the 'wiper position' column. One row has it as 1.211 and the other has it as 1.2109999999999...

I had this type of floating point error earlier with datetime. Best practices to avoid?

Comment: floating-point equivalence is a difficult manner. (just one example: math.e**math.log(10) is not 10.0). you may want to do some rounding before dropping duplicates, but even that doesn't guarantee success.

Comment: @Roy2012 Yes unfortunately rounding seems to be the best option at this point...

Answer (score 2):

Is there any similar rows in your dataframe, if not duplicated method return true for the second occurrence for the same rows for exp:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[1,2,3]],columns = ["a","b","c"]) 

df.duplicated()

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Edit: You have to consider drop_duplicates() method doesn't edits your original dataframe, it returns a copy of it, so you have to assign it manually.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

also you can give supset for testing spesific columns such as ->

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['sonde_id','..','...etc'],keep='last')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, drop_duplicates does not return true for the two rows I show in the example despite being identical.

Comment: I have the same issue! drop_duplicates doesn't always drop exact duplicates